# Cannot Deserialize JSON data returning from .net web service in to C# object in an web application

Tags: c#, json

I am returning JSON data from a .Net web service in the form of

```
<string>[{"Response":"78.00"}]</string>
```

and on another web application when I am trying to deserialize the JSON string to C# object its throwing an error

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'GetData' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g.
>   {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either
>   change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the
>   deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection
>   interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be
>   deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added
>   to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

The code I'm using is below

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetData objGD = new GetData();
        wbRfrnc.TransactionPut obj =new wbRfrnc.TransactionPut();
        string result = obj.GetPoint(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text);
        objGD = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetData>(result);
        Response.Write(objGD.Response); 
    }
public class GetData
{
    public string Response { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I Want to retrieve the key and value of JSON String [{"Response":"78.00"}]   in to 2 different  string variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing an array as you said but are trying to deserialize just an element.

The right code should look like this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    wbRfrnc.TransactionPut obj =new wbRfrnc.TransactionPut();
    string result = obj.GetPoint(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text);
    var objGD = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetData[]>(result);
    Response.Write(objGD[0].Response); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting back an array you need to deserialize to an array.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<GetData> data= new List<GetData>();
    wbRfrnc.TransactionPut obj =new wbRfrnc.TransactionPut();
    string result = obj.GetPoint(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text);
    data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GetData>>(result);
    if(data != null && data.Any())
      Response.Write(data.First().Response); 
}
```

Deserializing to a list will allow you to add multiple responses if needed but if you will only ever need 1 response it would be better to send just the object rather than an array. Then you original code should work and intent would be expressed in the code.